# How to get the failing column name for ora-01722: invalid number when inserting

Tags: oracle, insert-into, ora-01722

How to get the failing column name for ora-01722: invalid number when inserting.

I have two tables. Table A - all hundred columns are varchar2 and table B one half varchar2 other half number.

```
table A ( c1 varchar2(100), c2 varchar2(100) ... c100 varchar2(100) )
table B ( c1 number, c2 number .. c49 number, c50 varchar2(100), c51 varchar2(100)  ... c100 varchar2(100) )
```

Need to load table a into table b. the mapping is not 1 to 1. column names are not matching.
    insert into b ( c1, c2, c3, c4 .. c50,c51 .. c100 ) select to_number(c20) + to_number(c30),  to_number(c10), to_number(c80) .. c4, c5 .. c40 from a.

It takes a lot of time to find the failing column manually in case of ora-01722.

So i tried - log errors into err$_b ('INSERT') reject limit unlimited.
It gives you failing rows, but not the column. 
Still need to find the failing column manually . Not much of help.

Tried error handling, but always get 0 offset position with
        exception  when others then 
        v_ret := DBMS_SQL.LAST_ERROR_POSITION;
        dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_stack);
        dbms_output.put_line('Error at offset position '||v_ret);

I could use custom is_number function to check if number before inserting.
But in this case I will get null target value not knowing if source is empty or it has wrong number format.

It is possible automate the process by running data check to find failing rows and columns.
If mapping is one to one - then simple data dictionairy query could generate the report to show what columns will fail.

```
select 'select col_name, count(*) rc, max(rowid_col) rowid_example from (' from dual union all
select txt from 
(
with s as ( select t.owner, t.table_name, t.column_name, t.column_id 
            from  all_tab_columns s join all_tab_columns t on s.owner =t.owner and s.column_name = t.column_name
            where lower(s.table_name) = 'a' and s.data_type = 'VARCHAR2' and
                  lower(t.table_name) = 'b' and t.data_type = 'NUMBER'     )
select 'select ''' || column_name ||''' col_name, rowid rowid_col, is_number('|| column_name || ') is_number_check from ' || owner ||'.'|| table_name || 
       case when column_id = (select max(column_id) from s ) 
       then ' ) where is_number_check = 0  group by col_name' 
       else ' union all' end txt
from   s order by column_id
)
```

If there is no one to one mapping between table columns, then you could define and store the mapping into a separate table and then run the report.

Is there something more oracle could help in finding the failing column?
Are there any better manual ways to quicly find it?

Comment: Do you suspect that all the invalid values are in just one column? If so, why? Then - are there really so many rows that fail, that you can't inspect them manually? If there is a very large number of rows with invalid strings (which are not numbers), what do you plan to do once you find them? Anyway: if the "numeric" columns are col51, col52 etc, you could do something like `select sum(col51), sum(col52), sum(col53) from A` - if it fails, you know at least one of the three columns has invalid data (and then you can repeat with individual columns); then then next three columns, etc.

Comment: If you suspect only a small number of columns have invalid data, you can "divide and conquer" - in one query try columns 51 through 75 and in the other from 76 to 100. If one of the queries runs OK, you already eliminated half the columns from suspicion. Then repeat.

Comment: Yes, we can do many things manually.
But Im interested in how to fully automate the process. 
See if there are some native oracle tools to help with the issue.

Your suggestion would not work.
We receive text files with changing specs.

We don't know how many columns or rows will fail.
Import file keeps changing and we have to react quick.
Noway I can check thousand of columns manually every day.

Comment: My proposed query will provide full report of failing columns, row counts, example rowids.
Wondering if somebody else had similar issue and what was the solution? 
Not interested in manual work.

Comment: Oracle 12.2 introduced several validation functions which you can use. What is your version?

Comment: We got both 11g and 12c

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0

what are those functions?